# Почему не подключается Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

По какой причине не подключается JQuery?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head-slider__slider').slick({
    
  });
});
```

P.S. Подключаю для слайдера, код подключения JQ скопировал с документации слайдера [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: `JQ` и библиотеки сторонние  , лучше подключить в `<head></head>`

Comment: @Air, попробовал, не помогло http://prntscr.com/j4ehpn
http://prntscr.com/j4ehws

Comment: Мне кажется вся проблема в defer, во первых defer гарантирует порядок только в рамках других defer. Во-вторых его рекомендуют использовать только для внешних скриптов. Попробуй вместо него обернуть все в $(document).ready()

Comment: а вы подключаете с внешнего ресурса?

Comment: Скрипты должны быть или внутри head, или внутри body, а они у вас ни там ни там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно подключили.Вы должны добавить ключевое слово **https:** перед каждой ссылкой чтобы сработало.

Я реализовал такую небольшую анимацию чтобы вы видели что все работает  и проблема в том что надо добавить полный путь к внешним ресурсам

```js
$(".single-item").slick({
 dots: true
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ссылки, начинающиеся с `//` — тоже правильные.

Comment: У меня вопрос: я подключаю так: если ссылка на библиотеку указана на ресурс в интернете, то все работает, а если я качаю либу и указываю на неё просто по имени, то ничего не работает, как правильно указать ссылку на библиотеку js если я её скачал и поместил в папку с проектом?